# Blank values in QtPropertyBrowser

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm using QtPropertyBrowser as a front-end for QSqlTableModel. So every field in the table has its own property in browser. It allows user to edit fields' values in database. But if the values in DB is NULL the property do not appear at all. I've tried something like that

```
item->setValue(QVariant());
```

But it results with segfault.

There is no problem whith string fields: if it is NULL I just insert QString("") and the value  field in property browser becomes blank. But what can I do with numeric data types?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution for this? I'm facing the same problem ;-(

Comment: @ludek-vodicka; My colleague solved this problem by modifying the source code of QtProperty framework the following way: If a property is nullable he creates a special editor with a "NULL" checkbox. If user sets it checked - the property become disabled.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I also had to reimplement a part of QtPropertBrowser framework for my purposes, so extending to NULL checkbox is possible and good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The *[documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qvariant.html#QVariant)* states that `QVariant::QVariant()` constructs an invalid variant. I would just give it `QVariant(0)` instead, which can be converted to most other types.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But there is some ambiguity: user cant understand whether "0" means NULL or it is the concrete value that was set before.

Comment: Btw, I have segfault on item->setValue(QVariant(0));  even at integer fields. Strange.

Comment: Was just a quick guess, been a while since I last used the Property-Editor. As @OrcunC pointed out, an invalid variant seems perfectly non-invalid :) Without having access to your code, what remains is my guess that your pointer-to-item is somehow invalid. You could of course use your debugger to step into the property editor; as it came from QtSolutions, the sources should be available to you (fear not before vendor suppplied code ;))

Answer (score 0):

I will make a **guess** based on QT documentation.

If your value is NULL you can create a property as if it was a group as below but this won't allow you to **edit** it. If not then create a property as you have been doing and set its value as usual.

```
//Create a property
QtVariantProperty *nullType = variantManager->addProperty(
      QtVariantPropertyManager::groupTypeId(), "Your property name");
```

[groupTypeId](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/solutions/4/qtpropertybrowser/qtvariantpropertymanager.html#groupTypeId) seems to allow QVariant::Invalid.